# Evaluate the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I struggle to solve this problem. I am not really sure what do after let $u=2 x$.

$$\int e^{2x}+ 2\sqrt{x} $$

Comment: I think you're missing a $dx$ in your integral

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your latex correctly,

You can proceed by separating the integrals into 2. One containign $e^{2x}$ and one containing $2\sqrt{x}$.

From there it should be obvious. The derivative of $e^{2x}$ is $2e^{2x}$, so how can you deal with this in reverse? Also, you have a function in the form of $x^n$ which integrates to $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n + 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

First, split the integral into two integrals:

$\int e^{2x} dx + \int 2x^{\frac{1}{2}} dx$

The second integral is easy. For the first, yes, you can do substitution, by letting $u=2x$, which gives you $du=2dx \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} du=dx$. Now go back and substitute your first integral with this one:

$\frac{1}{2} \int e^u du= \frac{1}{2}e^u=\frac{1}{2} e^{2x}$

Answer (score 0):

$\int e^{2x}+ 2\sqrt{x} \,dx  = \int e^{2x} \,dx+ \int 2\sqrt{x} \,dx$

So you can solve these two seperately then add them together. With the first integral, you can use a $u$-substitution:

Let $u=2x$. Then $du=2 dx \implies dx=\frac{du}{2}$

So we have: $\int e^{2x} dx=\int e^u \frac{du}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\int e^u=\frac{1}{2}e^u$

Now substitute the $2x$ back in for $u$. So we have $\frac{1}{2}e^u=\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}$

This is the solution to the first integral. Can you solve $\int 2\sqrt{x} \,dx$ on your own? If so, just add the two solutions together and you'll have your answer. If you can't solve the second integral, let me know in the comments and I'll walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the integral into two:

$$ \int{e^{2x}\,dx} + \int{2\sqrt{x}\,dx} $$

which is:

$$ \left[\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}\right] + \left[\frac{4}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right] + C$$